# React boilerplate page is reloading on route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-boilerplate

I am using react boilerplate for my app and it is behaving very strange. 
I have multiple pages and some pages are working fine and on some pages my app is reloading means its refresh the page.

E.g on

www.myapp.com/login its working fine as a single page.

[image: Network Calls]

but on www.myapp.com/about its reload the whole page just like I am opening home page very first time.

[image: Network calls]

Did not understand why this is happening.

FYI: React boilerplate is using **Suspense** and **Lazy** to load the component.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be issue with routing.

In case of `www.myapp.com/login` you might have used some routing package (react-router) and added specific route, component to load and used a `<Link to="/login" >Login</Link>` component to route to /login page.

Where as for `www.myapp.com/about` page, instead of using a 
`<Link to="/about">About</Link>` to route to `/about`, you might be doing `<a href="/about">About</a>` which causes reload of the webpage.

Comment: Yes you are right. Already fixed the issue. I know silly mistake ;)